# Efficient way to create list of same numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most efficient  way to create list of the same number with n elements?

Comment: Are you really asking for the "**most efficient way**", or would any correct way suffice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
number = 1
elements = 1000

thelist = [number] * elements
```

---

```
>>> [1] * 10
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

---

NB: Don't try to duplicate mutable objects (notably lists of lists) like that, or this will happen:

```
In [23]: a = [[0]] * 10

In [24]: a
Out[24]: [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]

In [25]: a[0][0] = 1

In [26]: a
Out[26]: [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

---

If you are using numpy, for multidimensional lists [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is your best bet. It can repeat arrays of all shapes over separate axes.

Comment: The question is tagged `numpy` too, so maybe mention `numpy.repeat(1, 10)`?  (Although it'll be slower than multiplying a list until `n` is really big.)

Comment: Note that this may have unexpected results (depending on how much you know of how Python variables work) with mutable types - it produces a list of references to the same object.

Comment: To honor the numpy tag, `a = np.empty((elements,), dtype=np.int); a.fill(number)` is much faster than `[number] * elements` for higher values of `elements`. But the return is not a real list.

Comment: @Jaime: Also note that `empty` + `fill` is faster than `repeat`